# linux squid kerberos group filter with ext_kerberos_ldap_group_acl

Tags: linux, group, acl, squid

i setup a new squid under redhat 8 and follow the instructions on

[Redhat 8 Squid](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/deploying_different_types_of_servers/configuring-the-squid-caching-proxy-server_deploying-different-types-of-servers) under 6.3.

All fine. Kerberos authentification works. Now i want to limit the users on a specific group. So all users in group Web should be able to use squid. In my opinion i should use ext_kerberos_ldap_group_acl. So read some post to setup this but squid allow all users. So this is my implemantation:

```
external_acl_type ldap_group ipv4 ttl=3600 negative_ttl=1800 %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_kerberos_ldap_group_acl -g "Web" -b "ou=Users,dc=xxx,dc=xxx"
    
acl AUTHENTICATED proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl Web_user external ldap_group
http_access allow Web_user all
```

Can you please give me some advices what can i do to troubleshout or to change. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Do you have `http_access deny all` in you configuration? Without this, all users will be accepted

Comment: yes, as the last one i have this in my config